# Customise ActiveModel full_messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, activemodel

I would like to remove the attribute from my custom validation messages and just display the message, so instead of

```
School Please Provide Your School Name
```

I want to return

```
Please Provide Your School Name
```

As set in my model here

```
validates :school, presence: { message: 'Please Provide Your School Name' }
```

The message gets returned as JSON response.

Looking at the full_messages method

```
# File activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb, line 348
def full_messages
  map { |attribute, message| full_message(attribute, message) }
end
```

Could I override this with

```
# File activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb, line 348
def full_messages
  map { |attribute, message| full_message(message) }
end
```

I have tried this

```
module ActiveModel
  class Errors
    def full_messages
      map { |attribute, message| full_message(message) }
    end
  end
end
```

Located at `/lib/active_model/errors.rb`

but when i try to run my tests (rspec) I get the error

```
/home/richardlewis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@lnf_api/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/validations.rb:297:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

I load the file in my application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

How can i solve this please?

Thanks

EDIT

Controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
respond_to :json

def create
 @user = User.new(registration_params)
   if @user.valid?
     @user.save
     render json: { message: I18n.t("devise.registrations.signed_up_but_unconfirmed") }, status: 201
   else
     render json: { message: @user.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
   end
end

protected
def registration_params
  json_params = ActionController::Parameters.new(JSON.parse(request.body.read))
  json_params.require(:user).permit(:username, :school, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
 end
end
```

Comment: You've mentioned the problem in your tests - could you provide the code that causes the error?

Comment: apologies, i worded it incorrectly..When i run rspec no tests will run because of that error

Comment: Ok, now I see where the problem is coming from. Could you add code of your controller, where the unexpected message is generated for you?

Comment: do i need to require/load/include the module within the controller ?

Comment: Im getting `load_missing_constant': Unable to autoload constant ActiveModel::Errors, expected /home/richardlewis/Rails/lnf_api/lib/active_model/errors.rb to define it (LoadError)`

Comment: Well, I don't think you should overwrite `ActiveModel::Error` at all. I'll try help you to figure out what is wrong in your controller (that generates improper error) but you have to update your question, and add code of the problematic action.

Comment: ok i will add the controller code now

Comment: Could you add code of your `User` model as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`full_message` expects the two arguments `attribute` and `message`.

Update: Avoid monkey patching and edit your locale file to have something like:

```
en:
  errors:
    format: "%{message}"
```

Comment: yes this would be a much better way forward, as opposed to override existing behaviour..Im getting syntax errors a sec but its two spaces per new line isnt it?