# Customized validation messages in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called `user.rb`. This model has a customized email validation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable and :timeoutable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable #,:validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  validates_presence_of :email,:message=>"El campo email is requerido"

end
```

The problem is that the browser shows "*Email* El campo email is requerido" while I want "El campo email is requerido" (without Email before).

Answer (score 0):

As for Rails newer than 3.2.2, it uses the defined `errors.format` from the internationalization to build the validation full message.

I believe you cannot change the behavior for just one attribute, but if want to do it for the whole app, you can follow my answer on [Customise ActiveModel full_messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985474/customise-activemodel-full-messages/28988449#28988449)

One alternative is to define the message directly to the record's `base` so it can be printed as it is:

```
validate do |user|
  user.errors.add :base, 'El campo email is requerido' if user.email.blank?
end
```

Furthermore, a pull request is open to provide a solution on the attribute level https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/14260

Answer (score 0):

You can use [I18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) to change the translation of email to "El campo email"

```
activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: "El campo email"
```