# Hide/remove model name in association error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

For the life of me, I cannot find how to remove "model name" before the error message. Typically this would be ok but hear me out.

I have a model called 'foo'. I'd need to rename it at some point but for now it's a hassle. For now, I need to change the error message: "Foo How often you get paid is missing".

```rb
# finance.rb
belongs_to :foo # this will be renamed in the future
[..]
```

I thought I needed to edit the en.yml only:

```yml
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        finance:
          attributes:
            foo:
              required: "How often you get paid is missing"
```

This works but I don't need to show the model's name with the message. Ok I could do some string replace but that's ugly. Is it possible to only show the message in the `en.yml`?

EDIT:

Error are displayed as:

```
<% if @finance.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
    <% @finance.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an easy solution [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985474/customise-activemodel-full-messages). So in my case:

```yml
en:
  errors:
    format: "%{message}"
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        finance:
          attributes:
            repayment_type:
              required: "How often you get paid is missing"
```

This could be a duplicate post so you could mark as duplicate